# How to make global array not empty after async

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

hey I have trouble to access my global array, because it's empty. I know this question I already ask in this link [How to access global array in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976106/how-to-access-global-array-in-swift-4)

but they not show it in a code, so I don't understand how to implement it. can anyone show me how to do it? this is my code

```
var prayers = [Prayer]() //This is my global array

func fetchPrayer() {
    guard let city = self.city else { return}

    self.prayers = []
    APIServices.shared.fetchPrayer(name: city) { (results) in
        results.datetime.forEach({ (time) in
            let shubuh = Prayer(prayerName: "Shubuh", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PartlyCloudyNight"), prayerTime: time.times.Fajr)
            let dzuhur = Prayer(prayerName: "Dzuhur", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Sunny"), prayerTime: time.times.Dhuhr)
            let ashar = Prayer(prayerName: "Ashar", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PartlyCloudyDay"), prayerTime: time.times.Asr)
            let maghrib = Prayer(prayerName: "Maghrib", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Overcast"), prayerTime: time.times.Maghrib)
            let isya = Prayer(prayerName: "Isya", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Clear"), prayerTime: time.times.Isha)
            self.prayers.append(contentsOf: [shubuh, dzuhur, ashar, maghrib, isya])

        })
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.updateUI()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

This is my table view code, I put the func setupTableView in viewDidLoad

```
extension PrayerController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func setupTableView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(PrayerTimeViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellId)
    tableView.separatorColor = .clear
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.rowHeight = 53
}

//MARK:- TableView
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return prayers.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PrayerTimeViewCell

    let prayer = prayers[indexPath.row]
    cell.prayer = prayer

    return cell
  }
}
```

This is where the code is have an error index out of range

```
func updateUI() {
    let prayer0 = prayers[0].prayerTime
    let prayer1 = prayers[1].prayerTime
    let prayer2 = prayers[2].prayerTime
    let prayer3 = prayers[3].prayerTime
    let prayer4 = prayers[4].prayerTime
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve]. How's `updateUI` defined? Are your `tableView` `dataSource` methods set up correctly? You should include those as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor okey I already fix my question, thank you to remind me :)

Comment: How can you be sure that there are five elements in the `prayers` array? Please show the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

First, how will you ever be sure that there are five prayers in the `prayers` array when up call `updateUI`?

Second, you should avoid possible concurrent access of the global variables. I would suggest to modify your code the following way:

```
APIServices.shared.fetchPrayer(name: city) { (results) in
    var newPrayers = [Prayer]()
    results.datetime.forEach({ (time) in
        let shubuh = Prayer(prayerName: "Shubuh", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PartlyCloudyNight"), prayerTime: time.times.Fajr)
        let dzuhur = Prayer(prayerName: "Dzuhur", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Sunny"), prayerTime: time.times.Dhuhr)
        let ashar = Prayer(prayerName: "Ashar", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PartlyCloudyDay"), prayerTime: time.times.Asr)
        let maghrib = Prayer(prayerName: "Maghrib", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Overcast"), prayerTime: time.times.Maghrib)
        let isya = Prayer(prayerName: "Isya", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Clear"), prayerTime: time.times.Isha)
        newPrayers.append(contentsOf: [shubuh, dzuhur, ashar, maghrib, isya])

    })
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.prayers = newPrayers
        self.updateUI()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here, you create a local `newPrayers` array in the `fetchPrayer` closure. You fill the array, and after finished, in the main thread, you then "publish" your results by assigning `self.prayers` to the new array.

Nevertheless, in `updateUI` you should definitly check if you have the correct amount of elements in the array.

Comment: hey for your first question actually I always think that when I append in the completion block the value will store in my global array, but that's where the problem is I don't know that the async need to finish first. for the second question, I need to grab a value in a certain object so that's why I need use concurrent. is there another way to grab a value in a certain object?

Comment: To get an element out of the array, you first should check the `count` of the array to make sure the index is within a valid range.